# Entity Framework invalid connection string when under load

Tags: entity-framework, stress-testing

I'm encountering a strange issue where EF4 throws an `EntityException` reporting the provider failed on open when under stress. Normally, everything works well.

**Has anybody come across this problem before? Is there a solution?**

I've already checked that I'm closing the connection at the end of every transaction.

This is running in a WCF web service environment, where all database interaction is made with stored procedures through Entity Framework. The connection to the database is established in the service constructor, and then used as necessary in whatever service methods are called. `The exception is  thrown inside the constructor`

Comment: Andy can you provide a little more info?  Might help to see an example of the code too.

Comment: What do you mean by "under load"? How many concurrent requests is running in your service when this happens?

Comment: Sadly, not many. Maybe as few as 10 or 15!

Comment: Are there multiple threads trying to access the same context here?  If so, that might be the issue because the context isn't thread safe.  Just an idea.

Comment: how much stress?  During the stress, how many database connections do you see?

Comment: Each thread loads its own context, so I don't believe this should be an issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was relatively simple in the end: there was a single connection per request being made, never used and never closed. While this would have no noticable effect in low-load environments, under a higher load and combined with SQL Server's connection pooling, this quickly caused the SQL server instance to reach its connection cap!